# How can i set a button stay PRESSEDstay TOUCHED, after it is clicked,touched

Tags: button, onclicklistener, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I want to start 2 functions with a button(startButton). The problem is, when i start these 2 functions with the button, they start and after 1 second the functions are not responding anymore. I have to push the button again and again to restart those 2 functions. i have tried an OnClickListener method and an OnTouchListener method. Both are starting the functions,but after 1 second, the results are the same.

The StartButton calls it, but only for a second!!!

```
       btnStart.setOnTouchListener(object: View.OnTouchListener{
                                  override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                                        startTimer()
                                        startLocationUpdates()
                                        startDistance(location)
                                        startTempo()
                                      return true
                                  }
                              })
```

those 2 functions should be called/ works for a short time/1-2 seconds

```
    fun startDistance(location: Location): Float {
        val distance = mCurrentLocation?.distanceTo(location) ?: 0f
        mCurrentLocation = location
        if (location.hasAccuracy()) {
            totalDistance += distance / 1000 // zusätzliche Var für die gesammte Distanz
            tvDistanzKm.text = totalDistance.toString()
            tvDistanzTest.text = distance.toString()
        }
        return totalDistance
    }

    fun startTempo() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            if (location.hasSpeed()) {
                val getkmh = (location.speed * 3.6)//*3,6
                val kmh = getkmh.toFloat()
                totalTime += kmh
                normalTime = kmh
                timeDevided = normalTime / totalTime
                tvTempo.text = normalTime.toString()
                tvTempoTest.text = timeDevided.toString()
            } else {
                tvTempo.text = ("0.00")
                tvTempoTest.text = ("0.00")
            }
        }
    }
```

if anyone has a solution, a hint or an example.???would be great!!!
Thank you for your help.
Regards

Comment: button.setPressed(true), does not work

Answer (score 0):

Okay, because the button is still not working, even a Togglebutton doesnt work.I found a solution which works, but its just a solution for the moment.
i just took the away the fastest Interval and the interval from the function, and made a pauseLocation.
it works, but its not really a solution for the button!!!

```
    fun startLocationUpdates() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 2000
        mLocationRequest.interval = 5000
        fusedLocationProviderClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationRequest,
            mLocationCallback,
            mainLooper
        )
    }
fun pauseLocationUpdates(){
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        fusedLocationProviderClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationRequest,
            mLocationCallback,
            mainLooper)
```